# Solving a nested loop question in Swift Programming: The Big Nerd Ranch Guide

Tags: swift, loops

I am new to learning Swift and am trying to solve a challenge in Swift Programming: The Big Nerd Ranch Guide (1st Ed.). The question is in Chapter 6 about using a nested loop:

*Use a loop to count by 2 from 0 to 100. Use another loop to make sure the first loop is run 5 times. Hint: one good way to do this is to use a nested loop.*

I think I've found the answers but a bit unsure, any advise would be much appreciated!

```
for i in 1...5 {
    for i in 0...100 {
        if i % 2 == 0 {
            print(i)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would avoid using the same index variable, `i`, for both loops. That is confusing.

Comment: @Carpsen90: Not that I would recommend it, but you *can* have nested loops with the same name for the loop variable, the inner `i` then simply shadows the outer `i`.

Comment: @MartinR Good to know 

Comment: @Carpsen90  Because the question asks for the counts to be repeated 5 times so I thought the solution would be to nest the loop inside another that will make it run 5 times.

Comment: @delb99 If the goal is count from 0 to 100, using nested loops, with the outside loop running 5 times, then see my answer. If you want to count from 0 to a 100 five times then your code already works and you should take the comments from Duncan and Martin into consideration.

Comment: @Carpsen90 Great thanks very much for your help!

Comment: @MartinR: What does 'shadow the outer i' means?

Comment: @delb99: It means that the inner loop defines a local variable `i`, and inside the inner loop body you have no access to `i` from the outer loop.

Comment: @MartinR: Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically the solution is correct. However in Swift there are two more efficient syntaxes

1. Filter with `where`

   ```
   for _ in 1...5 {
       for i in 0...100 where i % 2 == 0 {
           print(i)
       }
   }
   ```
2. Loop with `stride` (recommended)

   ```
   for _ in 1...5 {
       for i in stride(from: 0, through: 100, by: 2) {
           print(i)
       }
   }
   ```

As the outer index variable is not used follow the ***replacing with '_'*** suggestion in the warning

Comment: I haven't seen the `where` qualifier on a for loop before. Where did you learn that? (Voted)

Comment: @DuncanC It's listed in [Swift - Summary of the Grammar](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/zzSummaryOfTheGrammar.html). The `where` clause is a common pattern in Swift. It can be used in `for` loops, `switch` cases, generics and as type constraint operator.